# createElement v html custom html string builder

Tags: jquery, createelement

If you want to create something like a table from parameters and insert into into a content editable div, is there a best practice method for this?

Originally I was doing passing the parameters, such as row and column numbers, into a couple of loops to build up the string of var html and then inserting it into the document via the execCommand('insertHTMl', null html);

I liked this method, as any classes or id's, inner html could be hard codded.

I came across the createElement command then which works but (unless i am doing it wrong) you have to add a log of appendChild lines if for each attribute or style you want to add.

Also I found it tricky to add some inner html to table cells, I wanted each table cell created to have a span node inside it but my loop only created it in the last cell - can anyone see what i am doing wrong here?

```
 mytable = document.createElement("table");
    mytablebody = document.createElement("tbody");
    myspan = document.createElement("span");
    newContent = document.createTextNode("Test text");
    myspan.appendChild(newContent);
    myspan.style.display = "block";
    myspan.style.width = "100%";

    for (var r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
        mycurrent_row = document.createElement("tr");


        for (var c = 0; c < columns; c++) {
            mycurrent_cell = document.createElement("td");                
            mycurrent_cell.appendChild(myspan);
            mycurrent_row.appendChild(mycurrent_cell);
        }
        mytablebody.appendChild(mycurrent_row);
    }
```

So for learning purposes anyhow, is there a particular reason this method should be used or is building up a string of HTML in some basic loops just as safe/acceptable?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Depends on source of data used for text. Using concatenated strings opens up potential for XSS injection whereas inserting into a node as text removes any html that may contain script tags

Comment: I see, thanks.  Do you know why from the above code the span was only being created in the very last cell of the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wanted each table cell created to have a span node inside it but my loop only created it in the last cell - can anyone see what i am doing wrong here?

You are appending the same node each time. Since a node can only be in one place at each time, it is implicitly removed from the previous parent. The proper way is to clone `myspan` each time.

```
mycurrent_cell.appendChild(myspan.cloneNode(true));
```

For other readers who want to reproduce this, you will need these 2 lines before and 2 lines after:

```
var rows = 2;
var columns = 2;

// ...

mytable.appendChild(mytablebody);
document.getElementById("test").appendChild(mytable);
```

...where the id selector refers to an existing element in the DOM:

```
<div id="test"></div>
```

> So for learning purposes anyhow, is there a particular reason this method should be used or is building up a string of HTML in some basic loops just as safe/acceptable?

Quoting **charlietfl**'s comment,

*Using concatenated strings opens up potential for XSS injection whereas inserting into a node as text removes any html that may contain script tags.*